# Does Python have an equivalent to (expression) ? option-1 : option-2 syntax?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, decision-tree

In java script there is an alternative to if statement i mean like ternary operator  : `(boolean expression )? option 1: option 2`, it is elegant compact and sometimes less confusing. I have searched a lot to find an alternative for 'if' statement in python but i couldn't find anything. Is there any way to trick python so we can avoid if statement ?

Comment: Thats not an if statement, its a ternary operator. Just do option1 if statement else option2

Comment: Maybe the keyword you can use is "inline if". There are some already solved questions with that keywords.

Comment: I don't mean any inline if statement , the point is avoid any if and else or case and switch

Comment: `option1 if condition else option2` **is** how Python spells the same thing that is, in JavaScript, described with the syntax `condition ? option1 : option2`.

Answer (score 0):

If expression:

```
option1 if boolean_expression else option2
```

Comment: See "Answer Well-Asked Questions" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, particularly guiding against answering questions you know are duplicative.

Comment: The inline if statement ain't any replacement for if statment

Comment: @SamFarjamirad, just because it uses the word "if" doesn't mean it's the same syntax. It's **absolutely** a different thing (different grammar in the parser even if it uses the same keywords).

Comment: @SamFarjamirad yes it is. It's an expression that yields a result, not just causes side effects.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks , but i'm already convinced , just one more thing, which one is faster ?

Comment: @SamFarjamirad, ..."faster"? Neither is necessarily faster. They do different things, as yuri pointed out above, and selection should be made in accordance with which one best models intent.